# What are some scientific and education fitness magazines?

Tags: workout-routines, exercise-technique

I may be an anachronism but I like to read magazines. For running I love [Running Times](http://www.runningtimes.com/running-times) and was wondering if there was something similar for strength training/general fitness. I'm looking for something that isn't full of a bunch of marketing fluff or "bro science"; something where I can get informative, educational articles, not the "blast your chest with body builder X's mind blowing extreme chest routine".

I looked and didn't see a similar question, if this isn't appropriate for the forum please feel free to delete. I also wasn't quite sure how to tag this. Thanks!

Comment: Your question is rather open-ended and is inviting multiple answers, all of which could be debatable and opinionated. I'm not convinced this is a good question for this site.

Comment: I agree with Matt Chan!  However, most of the fitness magazines that you can buy at the regular grocery or drug stores typically do not contain scientific evidenced.  These are what I would call "expert opinions."  You can however, check out scientific journal articles from NSCA, ACSM, NASM, etc. for more accurate and up to date information without being biased.  They often ask for a small yearly membership fee for you to gain access.

Comment: I was hesitant to ask because I find the question somewhat open-ended as well but I decided to throw it out there. If it needs to be deleted I understand completely. I'm looking for something less "Muscle and Fiction" and more of a "Kinesiology Monthly" if that helps.